# How to change new pfx cert file to old jks file in java project

Tags: java, keystore, pfx, jarsigner, jks

There is a java project, and has a jks certification file. But it is old (expired). Now i have to change it a new pfx certification file. But i don't know how i do it.

here is some information about current project;

this is pom.xml with old jks file configuration

```
<profile>
            <id>sign-base</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>sign</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>verify</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <storepass>OldJKSKeystorePass</storepass>
                            <keypass>OldJKSKeyPass</keypass>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-tsa</argument>
                                <argument>http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <keystore>${pom.parent.basedir}${file.separator}OldJKSFile.jks</keystore>
                            <alias>1</alias>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Here, there is a java class that name is "SpecialHttpsClient" extend default httpsClient, and it has a method like that. mykeystore file is under the resources package and i dont know about it.

```
private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        InputStream in =null;

        try {
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mykeystore");
            trusted.load(in, "mykeystorepass".toCharArray());

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(sslSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            return sf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("An error was occurred while creating SSLSocketFactory!***************", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if(in!=null )
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("An error was occurred while creating SSLSocketFactory!***************", e);
                }
        }
    }
```

Here is another class that name is SpecialHttpsConnection and has a method like that. I dont know anything about document file.

```
private static TrustManagerFactory getTrustManagerFactory() throws Exception {

        if(trustManagerFactory==null) {
            try {
                KeyStore trusted =null;
                trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                InputStream in = SpecialHttpsConnection.class.getResourceAsStream("/document");
                try {
                    trusted.load(in, "T1@ePudf27?wE".toCharArray());
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                }

                trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                trustManagerFactory.init(trusted);

            } catch(Exception e)  {
                logger.error("An error was occurred while creating TrustManagerFactory!***************",e);
                throw e;
            }

        }

        return trustManagerFactory;
    }
```

**My problem is that; how can i change "mynewcert.pfx" file with old?**

Comment: If you don't want to change your code, you have to convert your JKS file to PKCS12 file manually using `keytool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for jarsigner, may be useful for someone

open cmd and type **cd go to/ your/ jre/ bin/ directory/**

type

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "c:\mypfxfolderdirectory\mypfxfile.pfx" -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore "c:\mypfxfolderdirectory\myjksfile.jks"  -deststoretype JKS -srcstorepass pfxFilePass -deststorepass jksFileStorePass -srcalias 1 -destalias 1 -destkeypass jksFileKeyPass -noprompt

after that your jks file will created with two password: store pass, key pass.